# How can I build a C++ program in python?

Tags: python, msbuild, anaconda, mingw-w64

I am using Anaconda. I want to build a source code from github:
https://github.com/mmolero/pypoisson

When I use the following command in the terminal, it gives the following error:
Command: python setup.py build

Error:

> running build running build_ext skipping 'src\pypoisson.cpp' Cython
>   extension (up-to-date) building 'pypoisson' extension C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe
>   /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\Ibrahim
>   Khalilullah.conda\envs\PypoissonOpen3d\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include"
>   "-IC:\Users\Ibrahim Khalilullah.conda\envs\PypoissonOpen3d\include"
>   "-IC:\Users\Ibrahim Khalilullah.conda\envs\PypoissonOpen3d\include"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc
>   /Tpsrc\pypoisson.cpp
>   /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src\pypoisson.obj -w -fopenmp cl :
>   Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w' cl : Command
>   line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp' pypoisson.cpp
>   c:\users\ibrahim
>   khalilullah.conda\envs\pypoissonopen3d\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14)
>   : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define
>   NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe
>   /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\Ibrahim
>   Khalilullah.conda\envs\PypoissonOpen3d\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include"
>   "-IC:\Users\Ibrahim Khalilullah.conda\envs\PypoissonOpen3d\include"
>   "-IC:\Users\Ibrahim Khalilullah.conda\envs\PypoissonOpen3d\include"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc
>   /Tpsrc/PoissonRecon_v6_13/src/CmdLineParser.cpp
>   /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src/PoissonRecon_v6_13/src/CmdLineParser.obj
>   -w -fopenmp cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w' cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option
>   '-fopenmp' CmdLineParser.cpp C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe
>   /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\Ibrahim
>   Khalilullah.conda\envs\PypoissonOpen3d\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include"
>   "-IC:\Users\Ibrahim Khalilullah.conda\envs\PypoissonOpen3d\include"
>   "-IC:\Users\Ibrahim Khalilullah.conda\envs\PypoissonOpen3d\include"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc
>   /Tpsrc/PoissonRecon_v6_13/src/Factor.cpp
>   /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src/PoissonRecon_v6_13/src/Factor.obj
>   -w -fopenmp cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w' cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option
>   '-fopenmp' Factor.cpp C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe
>   /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\Ibrahim
>   Khalilullah.conda\envs\PypoissonOpen3d\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include"
>   "-IC:\Users\Ibrahim Khalilullah.conda\envs\PypoissonOpen3d\include"
>   "-IC:\Users\Ibrahim Khalilullah.conda\envs\PypoissonOpen3d\include"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc
>   /Tpsrc/PoissonRecon_v6_13/src/Geometry.cpp
>   /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src/PoissonRecon_v6_13/src/Geometry.obj
>   -w -fopenmp cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w' cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option
>   '-fopenmp' Geometry.cpp
>   d:\feasibilityanalysis2020_3\3dpointcloud3dvision\removenoiseandtin\code\pypoisson\src\poissonrecon_v6_13\src\Geometry.h(33):
>   fatal error C1189: #error:  OpenMP is required error: command
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe'
>   failed with exit status 2

Not only for this source code but also for other code fails to build.
It should be noted that I installed visual 2015, visual 2017, GCC compiler in my PC. The operating system is Windows 10.

Different source code needs different types of compiler, How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The critical section of that output is `fatal error C1189: #error: OpenMP is required`. At a guess, I'd say that this means that you need to have OpenMP available, and you don't. There's [another SO thread on installing OpenMP on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079586/getting-started-with-openmp-install-on-windows), which includes some [pretty recent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58834908/10993299).